# Spring Hibernate database query not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

Got this line to get list of "modules" by "course_id" from the database:

```
return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Module.class).add(Restrictions.eq("course_id",course_id)).list();
```

Upon run it fails with this error:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: course_id of: miniVLE.beans.Module
```

Course_id  - is a String. 
Could that be because course_id is a foreign key in the database?

```
@ManyToOne  
    @JoinColumn(name="course_id")
    private Course course;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you don't have course_id property in Module.class. 
In criterions you must use properties names and not column names. Or you don't have getter/setter such as getCourse_id()

Comment: So if I've got smth like "course" (see code above), I need to redeclare Restrictions.eq("course_id",course_id) to Restrictions.eq("course",course_id) and add getters for the "course"?

Comment: @exomen - Thanks for posting the final code to help others. However, instead of modifying this answer, you can post your final code as a separate answer.